# too long dataframe apply row functions

Tags: python, pandas

Read a csv file with time value in columns and get a dataframe with 1 columns values and datetime index most efficiently as possible. I do a read_csv, then a stack and the following function but it's more time and memory consumming.

Has someone a better way to do that ?

```
df.apply(lambda row: row['DATE'] + relativedelta( hours = int(row['level_2'][2:])), axis=1)

DATE        H01 H02 H03 H04 ...
2014/01/01  1.2 2.4 3.3 4.1
2014/01/02  4.3 2.6 3.2 4.1
```

And get:

```
DATE
2014-01-01 00:00:00    1.2
2014-01-01 01:00:00    2.4
2014-01-01 02:00:00    3.3
2014-01-01 03:00:00    4.1
```

Comment: Are there 24 columns? (i.e. is there a column for each hour?)

Comment: Answered for either case, I wonder if there is/should be a nicer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column for each hour (i.e. 24) and every date is present, then you'll be better doing the reshaping in numpy (it will be much faster), and just generating the DatetimeIndex via `date_range`.

Assuming the dates is the index (and it's a DatetimeIndex) and the other 24 columns are the hours:

```
vals = df.values.reshape(-1)
new_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], periods=24*len(df), freq='H')
pd.Series(vals, new_index)
```

Otherwise, you can create the new index using itertools product.... I would first make the columns Hours:

```
df.columns = np.arange(0, len(df.columns)) * pd.offsets.Hour(1)

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
            <0 * Hours>  <Hour>  <2 * Hours>  <3 * Hours>
DATE                                                     
2014-01-01          1.2     2.4          3.3          4.1
2014-01-02          4.3     2.6          3.2          4.1
```

*Note: Again, critical that DATE is a DatetimeIndex here.*

```
from itertools import product
new_index = [t + td for t, td in product(df.index, df.columns)]

In [21]: pd.Series(df.values.reshape(-1), new_index)
Out[21]: 
2014-01-01 00:00:00    1.2
2014-01-01 01:00:00    2.4
2014-01-01 02:00:00    3.3
2014-01-01 03:00:00    4.1
2014-01-02 00:00:00    4.3
2014-01-02 01:00:00    2.6
2014-01-02 02:00:00    3.2
2014-01-02 03:00:00    4.1
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is `stack`. More information in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking

Basically, you're looking at using stack and then converting `Hxx` to `xx:00:00` which should be straightforward.

Comment: It's that I actually do but it's a big longer and strong memory consumption (2 min for a file). There is a more efficient way to do this ?